# How to find row number of previous visible row

Tags: excel, vba

How can I color every other "group" of rows in filtered data?

Something like =MOD(SUBTOTAL(103,$A$1:$A2),2)=1 but for groups which will return TRUE AND FALSE in a helper column that is used to color on not color the row.

I have created a helper column which indicates whether or not to shade the row IF THE DATA IS NOT FILTRED but it obviously fails once a filter is applied.

Helper column formula in column T: `=IF(ROW()=2,FALSE,IF(Q2=Q1,T1,NOT(T1)))`

[image]

However if I filter to show only the Miami and Chicago locations I get this:

[image]

My helper formula is basing its results on the previous rows Job# and NOT the Previous VISIBLE row's Job#.

Is there some way to write a helper formula or macro that will only look at visible rows??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOOKUP with SUBTOTAL to find the last visible row:

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($Q$1,(ROW($Q$1:$Q1)-1),0,1,1))>0),ROW($Q$1:$Q1))
```

so:

```
=IF(LOOKUP(2,1/(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($Q$1,(ROW($Q$1:$Q1)-1),0,1,1))>0),ROW($Q$1:$Q1))=1,FALSE,IF(INDEX(Q:Q,LOOKUP(2,1/(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($Q$1,(ROW($Q$1:$Q1)-1),0,1,1))>0),ROW($Q$1:$Q1)))=Q2,INDEX(T:T,LOOKUP(2,1/(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($Q$1,(ROW($Q$1:$Q1)-1),0,1,1))>0),ROW($Q$1:$Q1))),NOT(INDEX(T:T,LOOKUP(2,1/(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($Q$1,(ROW($Q$1:$Q1)-1),0,1,1))>0),ROW($Q$1:$Q1))))))
```

When not visible it will error but it is not seen:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. Saving for future use. I was partly there but still far off.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly! Any chance you could explain how this works?

Comment: `SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($Q$1,(ROW($Q$1:$Q1)-1),0,1,1))` returns an array of `1` and `0` to the lookup the lookup then returns the last row where it was 1.  The index then returns the value of the cell at the row from the lookup in the column in the first criterion.  After that it is just logic like you had it.  @PhilNBlanks

Comment: @Scott Craner
Thanks for the explanation.  It took me a while to understand the 1/Subtotal, because the MS docs didn't specifically say that Lookup ignores errors, so that effectively keeps the results in order.  One question:  Is there any reason for the >0 on the Subtotal?  I realize it changes it to true/false, but is there really any need? I tested with and without it, and with my data, it seems to be the same.  But that could just be my data, and I might be missing the reason for it.